# Add an alias in postfixadmin with smtp access

Tags: email, smtp

I want to create a second identity `support@mydomain` which I want to send emails from. My mailbox is `info@mydomain`, so receiving emails should still go into this same info@mydomain mailbox.

In my admin interface [Postfix Admin](http://postfixadmin.sourceforge.net/) I can either

- create an **new mailbox** support@mydomain in virtual list with IMAP and SMTP access and password
- or I can create an **alias** that redirects support to info, but then I cannot use SMTP with this email.

And I cannot create both.

How can I create an alias `support@mydomain` that is redirected to my other email `info@mydomain` without having to create a new mailbox (which I don't need)?

[image]

Comment: The question doesn't make sense.  You say you can create either a mailbox or an alias but not both, then you ask how to create an alias.

Comment: I reordered my question is it clearer now what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole purpose of an alias is that you don't need a mailbox.

If you want support@ to go to the info@ mailbox simply create the alias and forward the mail there.  It is that simple.

Comment: But then I cannot send with that email in the "from"header

Comment: You never said you wanted to in the original question.

It depends on the mail client you are using.  Most will allow multiple identities.

Comment: Oh, yes you did.  But my comment stands.

Comment: Steve is right, most mail clients will allow multiple `From:` identities, including many webmail programs..